# List views in delta-lake

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I'm trying to figure out a way to list the views in a given delta-Lake database? Is there anything available that's equivalent of sqlServer's INFORMATION_SCHEMA or something obvious that I'm missing? I have tried the following without any luck:

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS")
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delta Lake is not a database. It's a type of tables sitting in your Hive Metastore.

If you would like to see views in a database, you can use Spark SQL [SHOW VIEWS](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-ref-syntax-aux-show-views.html) command.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but sadly we're on 2.4.3 which doesn't seem to support `SHOW VIEWS`, though show tables had it listed out along with tables which I'm perfectly fine to have for now as we have the names with prefix vw for views.